# css isolation with Blazor - css doesn't change my .razor

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor

In projectname.Client I created a folder `foldername`.

Inside that folder I created an razorfile `razorfile.razor`.
I also created an .css file `razorfile.razor.css`. In my solutionexplorer I can expand `razorfile.razor` and see `razorfile.css.razor` in it.

In my razorfile I have written this:

```
@page "/example"

<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section class="content">
            <div>
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
}
```

(Sorry about all the `div`-tags. I read that it supposed to help with the .css)

My .css file looks like this:

```
::deep h1 {
    color:brown;
}

h1 {
    color: brown;
}
```

My problem is that the text inside `h1` is not brown. How do I use the .css for that razor component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this link tag manually to the host page in the head tag (with your project name). Blazor does not do this automatically. Also make sure your project is on net 5.

```css
<link href="MyProjectName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

More on the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS file in wwwroot folder and add its reference in the index.html